# How to create a metagrammar?

Tags: grammar

I'm currently learning syntactic analysis. I'm trying to make a metagrammar that could generate that particular grammar:

```
A ⇒ A '+' C | C ;  
C ⇒ C * Q ;  
C ⇒ Q ;  
Q ⇒ a | b | 'A' | "B" | "(" A ")" | <num> ;  
<num> ⇒ <Signed Int> | Float ;  
<Signed Int> ⇒ Signe Int ;  
Signe ⇒ '-' | '+' | ~eps~  
<Int> ⇒ Digit Int | Digit ;  
Digit ⇒ '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | "9" | "0" ;  
Float ⇒ Int '.' Int ;
```

Where `<>` are ignored (i.e. `<int>` is the same as `int`), single/double quotes are for a string, `~eps~` is for epsilon. Everything else is considered a symbol (whether it is terminal or nonterminal).

Currently I have something like this:

```
S ⇒ left "⇒" right ";" | ε  
left ⇒ symb | "<"symb">"  
right ⇒ QP
Q ⇒ symb | """symb""" | "'"symb"'" | "<"symb">" | ε  
P ⇒ symb | '|' Q | ε
```

But it feels so wrong to me and I'm not so sure on what do to. Is there a method to determinate a metagrammar? How could I go about this one?

Comment: Should there be a `;` at the end of the line with `Signe ⇒ '-' | '+' | ~eps~`?

Answer (score 2):

Not a bad start.   You really should define symb:

```
letter = "A" | "B" |  ...  | "Z" ;
symb = letter symb | letter ;
```

But your metagrammar only allows one grammar rule.
To allow multiple rules, I think you want to write:

```
 S = R S | ε ;
 R = left "⇒" right ";"
```

You might be very interested in tools that use metagrammars to process themselves and other grammars.   This small paper about [MetaII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/META_II), from (ready?) **1964** discusses the issue and shows how to build compilers using it.  This is a stunning paper, and it will twist your brain (in a good way!)

When you are done with this paper, you will feel *very* comfortable with metagrammars.  (I learned to build compilers using this back in the early 1970s).